# How to load div content after time. SetTimeout(), Load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I need load content of div, 2 sec after click button. Content is other html file. When i use

```
     setTimeout($(".frame").load(this.href),5000);
```

div load content of file instantly. HELP

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".test").click(function(event) {
         setTimeout($(".frame").load(this.href),5000) ; 
 });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

```
setTimeout($(".frame").load(this.href),5000);
```

You are *running* `$(".frame").load(this.href)`, and passing the *result* of that expression to setTimeout.

You should put it inside an anonymous function instead, which involves caching the this variable (as pointed out by @hindmost):

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".frame").load(self.href);
},5000) ;
```

Comment: `this` will lose its context inside anonymous function. So you have to store it in separate variable

Comment: Thanks very much! Work! Im so noob. ;(